# Is it possible to compute the second stereo track if one has a mono track and one of the stereo tracks?

Tags: sound

I'm curious about Mathematica's capabilities to process audio files.

Suppose I want to reconstruct a stereo audio track. The first bit of information I have is a mono track made from a stereo to mono converter. Essentially, this is a physical device that takes both audio tracks in the stereo file and adds them together, but also it normalizes the output track.
The second bit of information is one of the stereo tracks.

I wish to reconstruct the other stereo track. How would I go about this?

Comment: Say the mono track is the average of the left and right channels m(t) = 0.5*( l(t)+ r(t) ). Now you have m(t) and r(t) -- how would you find l(t)?

Comment: @bills With neural network!

Comment: In general there is no way to predict what is on the opposite channel of a stereo recording. Do you have a particular situation in mind?